# Export ADObject data to CSV

Tags: powershell

Basically, I want to create a pscustomobject to correct the headers when ADObject data is exported. I'm not sure if it's possible to pipe a foreach into the code I have, or which way to go exactly. So far The current code I have does export to the csv, but not in the format I'd like it to be.
I have noticed the foreach I currently have only sees the elements in the array, but does not pull the actual data within the element.

Have already tried creating a pscustomobject but it's not outputting the actually data. It just creates the headers.

```
$ou_Array = $pOU, $lou, $fOU, $vOU, $cOU, $aOU, $auOu
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)

$get_Data = 
(Get-ADObject -Filter "created -lt '$date'" -SearchBase $ou_Array[0]),        
(Get-ADObject -Filter "created -lt '$date'" -SearchBase $ou_Array[1]), 
(Get-ADObject -Filter "created -lt '$date'" -SearchBase $ou_Array[2]),
(Get-ADObject -Filter "created -lt '$date'" -SearchBase $ou_Array[3]), 
(Get-ADObject -Filter "created -lt '$date'" -SearchBase $ou_Array[4]), 
(Get-ADObject -Filter "created -lt '$date'" -SearchBase $ou_Array[5]),
(Get-ADObject -Filter "created -lt '$date'" -SearchBase $ou_Array[6])

$Results = foreach ($item in $get_Data) {
    $DN = $get_Data.Context.PostContext | Where-Object {$_ -match 
    "DistinguishedName"}
    $Name = $get_Data.Context.PostContext | Where-Object {$_ -match 'Name'}
    $OC = $get_Data.Context.PostContext | 
    Where-Object {$_ -match 'ObjectClass'}

[pscustomobject]@{

    'DN' = $DN 
    'Computer Name' = $Name
    'Object Class' = $OC
    }
}
$Results | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop\results1.csv"
```

Expected results would be corrected headers with the data. Actual results is corrected headers, but no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Export-CSV` instead of `Out-File`.

Comment: Well, that worked great. Saved a ton of unnecessary code.. Thanks!

Comment: Often it just takes a second set of eyes.  :-)